# Can I render the same SKScene to two different views simultaneously?

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

I want to render two SpriteKit `SKView`s at the same time which share a common `SKScene`. I'd like each `SKView` to show a different part of the scene (e.g. from a different `SKCameraNode`). Is this possible?

**What I've tried:** I've instantiated two `SKView`s and called `.presentScene(mySharedScene)` on both of them. I can render those views simultaneously and animations work just fine. But since the camera position is set on the `SKScene` itself via the `.camera` property, I can't assign a different camera to each `SKView`.

Ultimately, I'd like to create a simple bouncing ball that leverages SpriteKit's physics engine. Each `SKView` will be displayed on a different physical monitor, and the ball should be able to bounce between them. I'm doing this purely as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can,  I have done split screens before, but let me tell you.  It is a real pain.  All of your updates get called twice, so you are going to have to develop a system that works around it.  Instead, for a simple experience I recommend copying your scene to your 2nd View then updating your camera to your new location.

```
func didFinishUpdate()
{
   let copy = scene.copy()!
   view2.presentScene(copy)
   copy2.camera!.position = newPosition
}
```

Comment: Yikes, that is a pain. But this seems like a workable solution for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: I am curious how this solves the OP's problem, which requires a single scene shared between two views -- not two separate scenes. Is it not true that`scene.copy()` would just create two separate, disconnected scenes?

Comment: It has been a long time since I dealt with SpriteKit. At the time of writing this, I believe the copy kept the same references to all of the nodes attached to the scene, so the only thing duplicated was the scene itself.