# How to create a mini-map of a SpriteKit scene using a different camera position

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a SpriteKit `SKScene` presented via SwiftUI `SpriteView`.

What I want is a mini-map that is a real-time duplicate of the `SKScene`.

So, whatever happens in the main scene also happens in the mini-map. In other words, I'm *not* interested in a simplified recreation of the scene.

This would be pretty simple if not for one very important detail: **The mini-map's camera needs to be scaled (which will make the camera "zoom out"). So, we're talking about two different cameras.**

If one camera was enough, I'd be able to simply use two `SpriteView` instances pointing to the same `SKScene`. But the need for a second camera is a challenge because an `SKScene` can only use one camera at a time.

The only other solution I'm aware of -- using `view.texture(from:)` or `view.texture(from:crop:)` to create an `SKTexture` of the rendered scene -- technically works, but has a hugely negative impact on performance when used in real-time. So that technique seems useless here.

Are you aware of any other strategy that might solve this problem?

Shaders maybe?

Or, is there a way to synchronize the rendering of two different `SKScene`'s so that they both show the same content, but from different camera positions?

Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697323/can-i-render-the-same-skscene-to-two-different-views-simultaneously?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C29.4767

Comment: BTW - this is easy with SceneKit. Create two `SCNView`, both pointing to the same `SCNScene`. Add a camera node to each scene view.

Comment: @HangarRash This question is about SpriteKit -- not SceneKit.

Comment: Yes, I know. The link I posted is about SpriteKit. My 2nd comment was just pointing out that your issue is easier to solve if you happen to be using SceneKit.

Comment: Not my vote. But the answer I linked does answer the other OP's question. That OP accepted it. That OP made a comment below that answer. Yes, it makes a copy. But look at the method it is doing it in. The copy is made anytime the original scene is updated.

Comment: You are right that I didn't notice the copy was being made each frame. I probably missed it because it's such an obviously inadequate solution. Creating and presenting a copy of an entire `SKScene` EACH FRAME will drop FPS to about zero for the vast majority of use-cases (if not all of them). I just tested it in my own application, and that's exactly what happened. @HangarRash

Comment: the "normal" way to do this is render-to-texture, which as you say involves a performance hit. although you can fake a zoom using the crop part of `view.texture(from:crop:)` which helps. keep in mind too that SKCamera just defines a point of view, it doesn't do any rendering. so having two cameras doesn't address the core issue (how best to render twice). i don't think normal shaders will work but have you looked into Metal and/or `SKRenderer`?